# How to make webpack, sass and source maps go along in a multi page app?

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, source-maps

Here's where I'm now:

`package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './1.js',
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.sass$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']},
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin,
    ],
};
```

`1.js`:

```
require('./1.sass');
```

`1.sass`:

```
body
    background: #ddd
```

Then

```
$ rm -f dist/* && ./node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

And open `http://example.com/dist` in Chrome. Then open `Developer Tools` > `Sources` > `top` > `webpack://` > `.` > `1.sass`. And there you'll see css code, not sass code. `devtool` is for js/coffeescript/whatever, if anything. What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**

From what I can see, `sass-loader` passes file [as a string](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/blob/d894345/index.js#L209-L214). And [in that case](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/255#issuecomment-32755577) `node-sass` (`libsass`) doesn't return source map. But even if given file, the latter returns source map with generated [css code](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1813), not sass code for some reason. Any workarounds are welcome, even if ugly.

Comment: Try `devtool: 'source-map'` and sourceMap query on sass loader too: `loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']`

Comment: @jali-ai [That's](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/blob/d894345/index.js#L289) how you pass map to the next loader, but `css-loader` [doesn't pass](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/blob/5651d70/lib/loader.js#L116-L122) it further. Css source maps are independent of js ones. As for `sourceMap` parameter, after looking into `sass-loader`'s code, `sourceMap` parameter indeed does something, but it doesn't work nevertheless. And yeah, I checked it with your correction. To no avail :( If there were some kind of workaround, even if ugly...

Comment: Actually it maps to the equivalent `scss` code of the `sass` file. So it's working in a way but not quite exactly the way you expect. If you use a variable or something that makes a different between css and scss you can see it.

Comment: I just pointed out something to notice. I think you can provide more useful information you gathered through your search, as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue with `libsass` not generating source maps for inline content seems to be [taken care of](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/650). It's just that `libsass` returns source maps with [scss code](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1813), even if given sass code. So I mistook it for css.